# Extreme directions of $S=\{x:-x_1+2x_2\le 4,x_1-3x_2\le 3,x_1,x_2\ge 0\}$

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

> Consider the set $S=\{x:-x_1+2x_2\le 4,x_1-3x_2\le 3,x_1,x_2\ge 0\}$. Identify all
>   extreme points and extreme directions of $S$. Represent the point $(4,1)^t$ as a
>   convex combination of the extreme points plus a nonnegative combination of
>   the extreme directions.

Recall:

**Definition:** $d\in \mathbb R^n$ is a extreme direction of $S$ if $d=\lambda_1d_1+\lambda_2d_2,$ then $\lambda d_1=d_2.$, where $d_1,d_2$ are directions of $S.$ and $\lambda>0,\lambda_i>0$

---

**This is what I've done:**

I draw the region and I found 3 extreme points $(0,0),(0,2),(3,0).$

And I don't know how to identify the extreme directions, I don't even see it geometrically.

How can I see it geometrically?

For instance the extreme points are "the vertex of the figure". So the extreme directions are ... ?

And finally, how do I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the graph at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sarf5jl1cq

Extreme directions are $(2,1)$ and $(3,1)$, which are the direction vectors emanating from the two nonzero extreme points in the boundary.

Comment: $(2,1)$ and $(3,1)$ emanate from $(0,2)$ and $(3,0)$ respectively?

Comment: :( ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes, this is correct.